# sending data to event handler when the event is called programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, call, eventhandler

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    Team T = new Team();
    string[] TLeaders = T.GetAllTeamLeaders(Session["USER_EMAIL"].ToString(), Session["ProjectID"].ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < TLeaders.Length; i++)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");

        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "Solid");
        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "lightblue");
        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "100px");
        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "1350px");
        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, "20px");
        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "white");
        DivRate.Controls.Add(createDiv);
        Label LeaderName = new Label();
        LeaderName.Text = TLeaders[i];
        LeaderName.Style.Add("margin-left", "600px");
        LeaderName.Style.Add("color","gray");
        LeaderName.Style.Add("font-size","20px;");
        LeaderName.Style.Add("margin-top", "10px");
        LeaderName.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
        createDiv.Controls.Add(LeaderName);
        RadioButtonList Rate = new RadioButtonList();
        ListItem bad      = new  ListItem();
        ListItem fair = new ListItem();
        ListItem  good= new  ListItem();
        ListItem veryGood = new ListItem();
        ListItem excellent = new  ListItem();
        bad.Value = "1";
        bad.Text = "Bad";
        fair.Value = "2";
        fair.Text = "Fair";
        good.Value = "3";
        good.Text = "Good";
        veryGood.Value = "4";
        veryGood.Text = "Very Good";
        excellent.Value = "5";
        excellent.Text = "Excellent";
        Rate.AutoPostBack = true;

        Rate.Items.Add(bad);
        Rate.Items.Add(fair);
        Rate.Items.Add(good);
        Rate.Items.Add(veryGood);
        Rate.Items.Add(excellent);


        Rate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return LeaderName('"+TLeaders[i]+"');");

        Rate.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CheckChange("s"));

        Rate.RepeatColumns=5;
        Rate.Width = 10;
        Rate.Height = 10;
        Rate.CssClass = "RateClass";
        createDiv.Controls.Add(Rate);

    }
}
```

so in this code I create a div and I place inside it a label and a Radio Button List however what i want to do is to create an event handler and send a data to it when i call it i call it like this:

```
   Rate.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CheckChange("s"));
```

and this is the event handler:

```
   protected void CheckChange(string s)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "", "fun('" + s + "')", true);

}
```

It give me an error "method name expected" when I send the data like this 
any solution?

Comment: You never said what error you got

Comment: it give me the error when i put the brackets when i call the event "()", if I remove them ever thing is okay, 

however I just want to know how to pass the data to the event

Comment: [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30362065/edit) and put the exact error message you are getting, your question is likely to be closed if you do not include more details.

Comment: "Method name expected"